# Programmatically restart windows to make system logs think user logged out

Tags: python, windows, automation

I'm hoping to make a quick script to log-out/restart windows at a set time. For example, start a script to "Restart windows in ten minutes". For this implementation I don't need it to run in the background or pop=up on its own. I just want to set the script and walk away knowing that the computer will log-out/restart at a set time.

**Why would I want to do this?**
On a corporate network, sometimes system logs will be reviewed and if one is found to be leaving X minutes too early, then complications arise. Kinda annoying.

**Did I already Google it?**
Yep. I found [this](http://kvance.livejournal.com/985732.html). But it wasn't too helpful. It requires a framework I couldn't find, and likely couldn't install since we don't have admin privs on these machines.

I'd like to use Python for it, and I'd really like for it to look like the user did it, not a script. Perhaps screen scraping would be the only way, and if so just point me to a quick guide or IDE and I'll post the source code for everyone.

**EDIT**: I also ran into [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/)

Comment: Just so that I am clear: You would like us help you con your boss into thinking you are staying until you are required, when you are skipping out ten minutes early?

Comment: You can edit your post with the new link.

If people are going so far as to look at logs for log-out time, and you're posting this from work, you should perhaps consider waiting until you're at home :P

Comment: @Andy oh don't worry, I've got it covered. Thanks for the edit tip. I completely forgot. and @kgrad 'con' my boss isn't the language I would use. :-)

Comment: Reminds me of a script I had to print my resume at work on a delay - this way I can make it to the printer before someone snags the copies...

Comment: @Jweede: 'Con' doesn't work? How about "rip off" or "steal from" - better for you? :-)

Comment: I prefer the term "borrow". :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shutdown command in batch will shutdown the computer

-s to turn it off,
-f to force it,
-t xx to have it shutdown in x seconds,

use the subprocess module in python to call it.

Since you want it to shutdown at a specific time, to automate the job completely you'd need to use something like autosys. Set the script up to call shutdown with a value for T equal to time you want to shut down - current time in seconds. Run it before you leave for the day, or have it set to run on start up and just ignore that stupid window it brings up.

Comment: perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: These tools look really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [shutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503.aspx) command in a batch script.